# ssh connection in C# windows 10 app

Tags: c#, ssh, windows-10

I have been looking far and wide for 2 days for something that can help me with this. I need a way to connect to an ssh server from a Windows 10 Universal app. This means that normal ssh libraries wont work, and tcpclient doesn't exist. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [SSH.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SSH.NET/) did not work?

Comment: correct, it uses stuff that isnt availiable in UWP

Comment: Surprising considering the description says "Silverlight 4.0, Silverlight 5.0, Windows Phone 7 and Windows Phone 8." It looks like a fairly compatible PCL library.

Comment: not for windows 10 apparently

Comment: The issue is that it cant find system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm

Comment: It may just need a recompile with the UWP box checked, HashAlgrothim is UWP compatible.

Comment: how do I compile it?

Comment: and I dont see Cryptography in system.security. So Idk

Comment: finally found the source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also failed to find SSH library which could be directly used in UWP App. There are several possible ways, hope it will help.

**Method#1: Port the SSH.NET to UWP**

Challenges - .NET for UWP did not provide the Socket Level Network API. It is impossible for a pure .NET library implement the SSH connection. It needs to leverage the Microsoft API in Windows Runtime Library.

**Mthod#2: Wrap an existing C/C++ SSH library like libssh into a Windows Runtime Component**

Challenges – the C/C++ library cannot use the API that are not allowed in UWP platform, else you cannot submit your app to the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/issues/4), SSH.NET supports UAP 10/UWP as of **SSH.NET 2016.0.0-beta1**.

You can download it here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SSH.NET

Then use it doing something like:

```
using (var client = new SshClient("hostnameOrIp", "username", "password"))
{
    client.Connect();
    client.RunCommand("...");
    client.Disconnect();
}
```

Comment: It does not work for me. When trying to connect to my ssh server (openssh), i get the following exception:

    Server response does not contain SSH protocol identification

Someone knows what the issue could be?

Answer (score 1):

For UWP use free [Asmodat NET.SSH library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Asmodat.Standard.SSH.NET/) - instead SSH.NET with code:

```
using (var client = new SshClient("hostnameOrIp", "username", "password"))
{
    client.Connect();
    client.RunCommand("...");
    client.Disconnect();
}
```

or paid [Chillcat](https://example-code.com/csharp_winrt/ssh_remote_command.asp)